The "Sender" bar is too large in IBM iNotes webmail (Lotus Notes)
I am using the web access IBM iNote. One day, I don't know why, my "Sender" bar in the IBM iNote is appearing too large. It is larger than the "Subject" and the "Date".
I have to click to check each email instead of just reading the Subject and knowing the approximate content.
Weird that I could modify the length of the column between "Subject" and "Date". But I cannot modify the length of the column between "Sender" and "Subject".
The large SUBJECT bar in IBM iNote:



Modifying the length between SUBJECT and DATE:



But I cannot modify the length between SENDER and SUBJECT:




Whoever flagged this as "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic..." didn't read the question. This is a valid question. As for an answer, I don't have one, unfortunately. I stopped using Lotus Notes > 10 years ago (thankfully)

@spikey_richie I suggested move to webapps because "I am using the web access IBM iNote". It's off topic here anyway.

It turns out I found the solution. I put the mouse on the gap between SUBJECT and DATE. Then I held and moved to the right. The SUBJECT became longer and longer.

Putting OP's answer from comments here:

Put the mouse on the gap between SUBJECT and DATE. Hold the button and move to the right. The SUBJECT will become longer.

